# Curvature of the boundary curve of convex set

Tags: differential-geometry, plane-curves

I've got a very simple question, but I can't get a rigorous proof. Suppose that $X\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ is a convex set, and suppose further that $\gamma$ is a closed regular curve with image $\partial X$. How to prove that the signed curvature is everywhere non-negative?

Comment: If you write the curve as a graph over it's tangent, then the graph is locally convex and you can use the local representation you on the wiki page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature to see this is true. You now only have to derive that formula. Btw, the claim depends on the correct orientation of the curve.

Comment: ? - Your assumption is global convexity and have asked why the sign of $\kappa$ is constant. If you write the curve as a graph over it's tangent in a given point you have to choose an orientation, which, for example, could result in the statement that the positive y-axis corresponds to the inner normal of the convex set. Then you locally alway have a convex function, hence a sign for the second derivative.

Comment: This is discussed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_curve (revision as of 10 Sept 2020). "A curve is called simple if it does not intersect itself. A closed regular plane simple curve C is convex if and only if its curvature is either always non-negative or always non-positive". There is a proof and reference in the article.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P\in X$. At each point of the curve, the curve is on only one side of the tangent, and it is the same side $P$ is on. You can readily translate this into statements about scalar products with normals and so on.

Comment: To be honest, this looks like handwaving to me.